# Installing Python Canopy in Active Directory with a Mandnatory Profile

Tags: python, active-directory, enthought

We are having difficulty installing our Python distribution in a way that will allow multiple users of the same computer to program in Python.

We switched the computers in our lab over to active directory with a mandatory profile. The problem is that Enthought Canopy puts several hundred MB of material in the profile itself. This makes it incredibly slow when a new user logs on. Can I get Canopy to install somewhere else, like a "normal" program?

Any help would be much appreciated, and I apologize if there is some obvious answer I am missing.

Comment: Enthought Canopy is a tool "used primarily for programming".  Not sure why this was marked "off topic", especially given the "enthought" tag.

Comment: @gddc, reto, Achrome, Mark -- what Alan said. Python is a programming language. Canopy is a Python distribution, set of scientific libraries ("packages" in Python parlance), and IDE. The purpose of Canopy is to write computer programs! Stack Overflow is the standard way for users to get community support for this PROGRAMMING environment. Please do your research before you suppress. And please remove this hold. -- Enthought tech support

Comment: @Eric Charles -- yes, you can install it for All Users, as described here https://support.enthought.com/entries/23736288-Windows-On-some-systems-admin-users-cannot-immediately-install-for-all-users-. Then you can do a "common install" as described here https://support.enthought.com/entries/26491185-Understanding-a-Canopy-system-wide-installation-common-install-. Then the footprint for each individual user will be very light.

Comment: @Jonathan, thanks for the links, but it is still not working for us. We follow those instructions, and it opens for the administrator account that was used to do the install. However, when you log in as a new user, it does not open and says "Failed to setup your environment - v1.4.1 (win-64bit)"